# How do I test that I have set up a many to many relationship correctly in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, activerecord

I am setting up a many to many relationship using the :through method and want to test that I have set everything up correctly.

```
class MenuItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :products #burger
  belongs_to :additions #extra mustard
end
```

Products would be something like hamburger

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :menu_items
  has_many :additions, through: :menu_items
end
```

additions would be something like extra mustard or pickles

```
class Addition < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :menu_items
  has_many :products, through: :menu_items
end
```

I have set up my fixtures so that a hamburger should have 2 additions associated with it. Now I want to test that the association works. Not exactly sure how to do this. I tried this:

in the fixture I set hamburger to have an id of 22. also set the burger to have mustard and pickles (2 additions).

```
test "product 22 should have 2 additions associated with it" do 
  menu_item = Product.find(22).additions
  assert_equal menu_item.count, 2 
end
```

I get an uninitialized constants error

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Product::Additions
```

I am sure that I am just misunderstanding something. Would really appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you need to use singular for belongs_to.

```
class MenuItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product #burger
  belongs_to :addition #extra mustard
end
```

Comment: Awesome. So, does my test make sense? or would you take another approach to this? I am new to a lot of the back-end stuff. I read somewhere else that it is not even really good practice to test the default functionality of the framework.

Comment: Well, there's a risk to testing that Rails works.  Here you are kind of testing that associations work and testing your fixtures.  Tests for associations should be testing the logic, and if the logic is trivial (like here) then don't need to have a test.  On the other hand, exploratory testing, and testing your setup, and then deleting the test is a good practice.  It encourages TDD by doing your exploratory development in the test harness.

Answer (score 0):

Check `shoulda-matchers` gem: https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers#activerecord-matchers